# Is there a solution in fixing 'MySQL connection not available' for very second request in Flask application?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-connector

I am running a Flask application on local and production server. I have no issues with the local, I am facing 'MySQL connection not available' for every second database request on production server. After reloading or after performing rollback operation, it is getting executed, but the issue repeats. I tried major solutions available on the internet by changing, pool_recycle, 'wait_timeout' and other timeouts to same value of 1600, but didn't work. I finally destroyed the application and reinstalled everything on the server but the issue is still on. Please help in this, thank you.

My production MySQL config:

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SECRET_KEY = 'secret_key'
    DEBUG=False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://{username}: 
        {password}@{hostname}/{databasename}".format(
           username="myusername",
           password="password",
           hostname="myhostname",
           databasename="mydatabase",
    )
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE = 299
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

Error Message:

```
Exception on /add_questions/1/2 [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 713, in _write_bytes
    self._sock.sendall(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 771, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 270, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 346, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 318, in _load_user
    user = self._user_callback(user_id)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/jaihindpro/application/auth/views.py", line 26, in load_user
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1004, in get
    return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_pk_identity)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1121, in _get_impl
    return db_load_fn(self, primary_key_identity)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 287, in load_on_pk_identity
    return q.one()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3360, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3329, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3405, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3430, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 984, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1103, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1288, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1482, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 590, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 771, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/home/ulznrcvr/virtualenv/jaihindpro/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))")
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.student_id AS user_student_id, user.role_id AS user_role_id, user.course_id AS user_course_id, user.sub_course_id AS user_sub_course_id, user.batch_id AS user_batch_id, user.full_name AS user_full_name, user.email AS user_email, user.phone_number AS user_phone_number, user.password AS user_password, user.active AS user_active, user.confirmed AS user_confirmed, user.confirmed_date AS user_confirmed_date, user.subscribed AS user_subscribed, user.start_date AS user_start_date, user.end_date AS user_end_date, user.re_url AS user_re_url, user.online AS user_online 
FROM user 
WHERE user.id = %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'param_1': 2}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself, I flagged "pool_pre_ping" attribute to "True" in engine settings.

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        "pool_pre_ping": True, 
        "pool_recycle": 300,
    }
```

Ref: https://medium.com/@heyjcmc/controlling-the-flask-sqlalchemy-engine-a0f8fae15b47

Comment: I was having this problem in my FastAPI project. This solution worked perfectly. I had to implement with params passed to create_engine:
`engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300)`
Haven't had a random 500 error since. Thanks!

Comment: I am not using SQLAlchemy. Just Django ORM with MySQL and I still face this issue. I don't have the "pool_pre_ping" value configured for it. How can we resolve that?

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol You can configure it in Django engine using  `engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@localhost/mydatabase', pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300)`

Comment: We're not using that function. the Database settings look like this:
DATABASES:{
    "default": {
        "Engine": "django.db.backends.mysql",
        "name": "XXX",
        "user": "XXXX",
        "password": "XXXX",
        "host": "XXXX",
        "port": "XXXX"
}
}

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol After "port" add this "'OPTIONS': {
            'pool_pre_ping': True,
            'pool_recycle': 300,
        }"

Comment: @Jitendra I'm not sure if those two variables are applicable if I am not using SQLAlchemy, since in my project we are directly making use of the Django ORM. Thoughts?

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol I understood about your concern, the suggested code is for Django ORM. Once, try it.